# Is there a way to choose the sorting of ksort?

Tags: php, ksort

I have a use for `ksort()` and I need to choose the sorting order(ASC/DESC).

Is there a way of doing it without `array_multisort()`?

Comment: After ksort try array_reverse

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`krsort()` for descending order
`ksort()` for ascending order

Comment: So why does it let you use the SORT_DESC flag?? So happy I found this answer - thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php has a very useful comparison of all the built-in sorting functions.

Answer (score 7):

Also :

`krsort()` function to sort an associative array in descending order, according to the **key**.
 
**&**

`ksort` for ascending order 
**plus**

`arsort()` function to sort an associative array in ascending order, according to the **value**.