# Why ksort does not work? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, ksort

If I run this :

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($a);echo '</pre>';
```

The result :

> Array (
>       [0] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => 3
>               [name] => chelsea.png
>           )
>       [1] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => 4
>               [name] => arsenal.png
>           )
>       [2] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => 5
>               [name] => mu.png
>           )
>   )

If I run this :

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($b);echo '</pre>';
```

The result :

> Array (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [id] => 1
>               [name] => city.png
>           )
>   )

Then I merge use :

```
$c = array_merge($a, $b);

echo '<pre>';print_r($c);echo '</pre>';
```

The result :

> Array (
>       [0] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => 3
>               [name] => chelsea.png
>           )
>       [1] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => 4
>               [name] => arsenal.png
>           )
>       [2] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => 5
>               [name] => mu.png
>           )
>       [3] => Array
>           (
>               [id] => 1
>               [name] => city.png
>           ) )

I want to sort the array by id

I try this :

```
ksort($c);
```

Then I run

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($c);echo '</pre>';
```

The result :

> Array (
>       [0] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => 3
>               [name] => chelsea.png
>           )
>       [1] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => 4
>               [name] => arsenal.png
>           )
>       [2] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => 5
>               [name] => mu.png
>           )
>       [3] => Array
>           (
>               [id] => 1
>               [name] => city.png
>           ) )

It does not work. Position id = 1 has a position at the very end. It should be in the first position

How can I solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230926/is-there-a-way-to-choose-the-sorting-of-ksort-like-asc-desc check it

Comment: @RohitS, Do not you read my question? I already use `ksort`

Comment: ksort does work (on it's own), it just does not work in your case, or better worded: you use the wrong function for the sort operation you'd like to do. - Please see existing Q&A resources about the general problem - like the one linked as duplicate - before posting another question. Otherwise future users will have more and more problems to locate a good solution for them fast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286597/using-usort-in-php-to-sort-an-array-of-objects

Comment: @TrendingNews not sure did you read the linked answer?? did someone said you didnt used something?

Comment: @TrendingNews Your `$a` is an array of objects, but `$b` is an array of array. So you   have to trans then into the same structure as array of array, or array of objects, or not trans them but with a complex compare function in the next sort process. As @mickmackusa's comment, then you can use usort to sort it.